# Create an Action<T> to "set" a property, when I am provided with the LINQ Expression for the "get"

Tags: c#, expression-trees

I'd like to be able to generate a compiled expression to set a property, given the lambda expression that provides the "get" method for a property.

Here's what I'm looking for:

```
public Action<int> CreateSetter<T>(Expression<Func<T, int>> getter)
{
    // returns a compiled action using the details of the getter expression tree, or null
    // if the write property is not defined.
}
```

I'm still trying to understand the various types of Expression classes, so if you can point me in the right direction that would be great.

Comment: Don't you mean `Action<T, int>`? Also, we could make `int` a type parameter too.

Comment: Ani, yes you're right - I meant Action<T, int> and int will of course be a generic parameter too.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Using @Ani's answer as a starting point, you can use the following to generate a **compiled expression**.

```
[TestMethod]
public void CreateSetterFromGetter()
{
    Action<Person, int> ageSetter = InitializeSet((Person p) => p.Age);
    Action<Person, string> nameSetter = InitializeSet((Person p) => p.Name);

    Person p1 = new Person();
    ageSetter(p1, 29);
    nameSetter(p1, "John");

    Assert.IsTrue(p1.Name == "John");
    Assert.IsTrue(p1.Age == 29);
}

public class Person { public int Age { get; set; } public string Name { get; set; } }

public static Action<TContainer, TProperty> InitializeSet<TContainer, TProperty>(Expression<Func<TContainer, TProperty>> getter)
{
    PropertyInfo propertyInfo = (getter.Body as MemberExpression).Member as PropertyInfo;

    ParameterExpression instance = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TContainer), "instance");
    ParameterExpression parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TProperty), "param");

    return Expression.Lambda<Action<TContainer, TProperty>>(
        Expression.Call(instance, propertyInfo.GetSetMethod(), parameter),
        new ParameterExpression[] { instance, parameter }).Compile();
}
```

You should cache the compiled expression to keep it handy for multiple uses.

Comment: Entirely true, but I'm not sure an expression is the best route here. But the example is a good one (for illustration).

Comment: I'm marking this as the answer as it uses the Expression classes as the solution, which is what I was looking for. Thanks Adam

Answer (score 7):

You could of course walk the expression-tree and then use `Delegate.CreateDelegate` to create the  appropriate `Action<,>`. It's quite simple, except for all of the validation-checks (I'm unsure if I've covered everything):

<s>I'm no expression-tree expert, but I don't *think*  building an expression-tree and then calling `Compile` is possible here since expression-trees can't contain assignment statements, as far as I know.</s> (**EDIT**: Apparently, these have been added in .NET 4. It's a hard-to-find feature since the C# compiler doesn't seem to be able to build them from lambdas).

```
public static Action<TContaining, TProperty>
    CreateSetter<TContaining, TProperty>
    (Expression<Func<TContaining, TProperty>> getter)
{
    if (getter == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("getter");

    var memberEx = getter.Body as MemberExpression;

    if (memberEx == null)
        throw new ArgumentException("Body is not a member-expression.");

    var property = memberEx.Member as PropertyInfo;

    if (property == null)
        throw new ArgumentException("Member is not a property.");

    if(!property.CanWrite)
        throw new ArgumentException("Property is not writable.");

    return (Action<TContaining, TProperty>)
           Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action<TContaining, TProperty>),
                                   property.GetSetMethod());
}
```

**Usage**:

```
public class Person { public int Age { get; set; } }

...

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var setter = CreateSetter((Person p) => p.Age);
    var person = new Person();
    setter(person, 25);

    Console.WriteLine(person.Age); // 25     
}
```

Do note that this creates an *open* instance delegate, meaning that it's not bound to any particular instance of `TContaining`. It's simple to modify it to be bound to a *specific* instance; you'll have to pass a `TContaining` as well to the method and then use a different overload of `Delegate.CreateDelegate`. The signature of the method would then look something like:

```
public static Action<TProperty> CreateSetter<TContaining, TProperty>
        (Expression<Func<TContaining, TProperty>> getter, TContaining obj)
```

Comment: Not sure, but I think they added assignments in .net 4. But the setter should already have the correct signature, so it's not necessary.

Comment: Yes, assignment is in 4.0 - but you really don't need it here; Delegate.CreateDelegate is ideal. +1

Comment: @CodeInChaos, @Marc Gravell: Thanks, that was news to me.

Comment: great answer too. Thanks.
@Marc, why is Delegate.CreateDelegate better than Expression.Lambda?

Comment: @Ani "Apparently, these have been added in .NET 4. It's a hard-to-find feature since the C# compiler doesn't seem to be able to build them from lambdas)." `int x; new Expression<Action>(() => x = 5);` - I believe this builds an assignment from a lambda, but I haven't actually checked this.

Answer (score 4):

Pointers only I'm afraid (I'm not at a pc) - but;

- the lambda's .Body will most likely be MemberExpression
- do a safe cast (`as` etc) and access the `.Member`
- since you belive this a property, this should be a PropertyInfo, so test/cast etc
- from a PropertyInfo, call GetSetMethod() to get the corresponding MethodInfo
- use Delegate.CreateDelegate to get that as a delegate (passing the action type)
- finally, cast the Delegate returned onto the *expected* delegate type