# Assign a value from an expression mapping

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, expression-trees

I map properties using `Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>`.

I've just needed to fetch property values from objects until know. How can I assign values using that expression?

Comment: You can't do it with that expression directly, you'll need to create an `Action<..>` (or an `Expression<Action<..>>` in tree form) to do that. See: Create an Action<T> to “set” a property, when I am provided with the LINQ Expression for the “get”. http://stackoverflow.com/q/4596453/412770

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this, assuming `expression = Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>`:

```
MemberExpression memberExpression;

switch (expression.Body.NodeType)
{
  case ExpressionType.Convert:
    memberExpression = ((UnaryExpression) expression.Body).Operand as MemberExpression;
    break;
  case ExpressionType.MemberAccess:
    memberExpression = expression.Body as MemberExpression;
    break;
}

var propInfo = memberExpression.Member as PropertyInfo;
```

then just use SetValue